# calculate steps of turtles among neighbors

Tags: netlogo

In the world, the two types of agents, individuals and messages, are randomly positioned in the two-dimensional attitudinal space.

If an individual believes the messages, he or she creates links with the messages.

Then, an individual adjusts his or her attitudinal position based on the calculation of distances from oneself to the messages.

Here, I have a problem.

**I would like to make an individual move twice more when exposed to a message with a high value than when exposed to one with a low value.**

But what I can do right now is just averaging the distance among the messages.

Here's what I've done so far

```
breed [individuals individual]
breed [messages message]
messages-own [value]
undirected-link-breed [messagelinks messagelink]

to setup
  ca
  create-individuals 100 [initiate-individuals]
  reset-ticks
end


to go
  new-messages
end


to initiate-messages
  ifelse random-float 1 < value-p [ set value "H" ] [set value "L"]
end

to initiate-individuals
  setxy random-xcor random-ycor
end

to new-messages
  create-messages 30 [
  initiate-messages
  ask individuals [
    integrate-messages myself
]
]
end

to integrate-messages [newmessages]
  if random-float 1 < 0.3
    [create-messagelink-with newmessages
    setxy mean [xcor] of messagelink-neighbors mean [ycor] of messagelink-neighbors]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making the assumption that `integrate-messages` is intended to handle a set of messages, even though when a receiver executes it in your code it is only the newly created message itself, not all newly created messages.  There are likely several ways to handle the problem of giving "H" messages more influence than "L" messages, but perhaps the most straightforward to simply to use a weighted average of the messages' xcors and ycors.  I've written a short model that does that in `integrate-messages`.

```
breed [messages message]
breed [receivers receiver]
undirected-link-breed [messagelinks messagelink]

messages-own [value]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-receivers 1 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set color green
  ]
  create-messages 5 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    set value ifelse-value (random-float 1 < 0.5) ["H"] ["L"]
    set color blue
    set label value
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask one-of receivers [
    integrate-messages n-of 3 messages
  ]
end

to integrate-messages [newmessages]
  ;to indicate which messages are being received.
  ask newmessages [set color red ]
  create-messagelinks-with newmessages [set color red]

  ;now calculate the weighted position relative to ALL linked messages.
  let mssgs [other-end] of my-messagelinks
  let wghts map [x -> ifelse-value ([value] of x = "H") [2] [1]] mssgs
  let xc sum (map [[m w] -> w * [xcor] of m ] mssgs wghts)
  let yc sum (map [[m w] -> w * [ycor] of m ] mssgs wghts)
  set xcor xc / sum wghts
  set ycor yc / sum wghts

  ;to show where the receiver ends up.
  set color red
end
```

Comment: It helped me a lot!! Thanks. But I have one more question.
When I run your codes with one turtle with a small number of messages, even though it creates links with all the messages, it moves back and forth. Given that its link composition with messages does not change, I assume that it should stay in its new position. Can you explain why?
By the way, I intentionally deleted the function for brevity, but the original 'integrate-messages' includes the criterion function such as turtles integrate messages only when the messages fall within their attitude limit. So I set turtles to execute it.

Comment: My mistake.  I've taken out the hatch command (it was creating new receivers!) and changed one line in the code above.  "let mssgs" was only looking at newmessages, not all the messages to which the receiver was linked.  This now seems to work.